# How do I move out of a struct that has a destructor, if I don't want to run the destructor?

Tags: rust, destructor, move-semantics

Suppose I have a Rust `struct` that has a destructor:

```rust
pub struct D1 {
    a: String,
    b: String
}

impl Drop for D1 {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("{0}", self.a)
    }
}
```

I want to implement a method that moves some or all of the fields out of the object, destroying it in the process. Obviously, that can't be done safely if the object's destructor gets run – it would attempt to unsafely read from the moved fields. However, it should be safe if the destructor is suppressed somehow. But I can't find a way to suppress the destructor in a way that makes the move safe.

`mem::forget` doesn't work, because the compiler doesn't treat it specially when it comes to destructors:

```rust
impl D1 {
    fn into_raw_parts(self) -> (String, String) {
        let (a, b) = (self.a, self.b); // cannot move here
        mem::forget(self);
        (a, b)
    }
}
```

and `ManuallyDrop` doesn't work either – it provides the interior data only via a reference, preventing a move:

```rust
use std::mem;

impl D1 {
    fn into_raw_parts(self) -> (String, String) {
        let md = mem::ManuallyDrop::new(self);
        (md.a, md.b) // cannot move out of dereference
    }
}
```

```rust
use std::mem;

impl D1 {
    fn into_raw_parts(self) -> (String, String) {
        let md = mem::ManuallyDrop::new(self);
        (md.value.a, md.value.b) // field `value` is private
    }
}
```

I could presumably solve this problem by dipping into `unsafe` code, but I'm wondering whether there's a safe way to do this – have I missed some API or other technique to tell Rust that I can safely move out of a value because I'm not planning to run the destructor?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in safe code to leave a type implementing `Drop` uninitialized. However, you can leave it initialized with dummy values:

```rust
use std::mem;

impl D1 {
    fn into_raw_parts(self) -> (String, String) {
        (mem::take(&mut self.a), mem::take(&mut self.b))
    }
}
```

This will leave `self` with empty strings (which do not even allocate any memory). Of course, the `Drop` implementation has to tolerate this and not do something undesired.

If the fields’ types in your real situation do not have convenient placeholder values, then you can make the fields be `Option`s. This is also a common technique when `Drop::drop()` itself needs to move out of `self`.